# Properties of DFT of Circularly Symmetric 2-D Matrices

Tags: image-processing, matlab, dft, linear-algebra

I'm very new in image processing and trying to get a grasp in the basic concepts in 2-D DFT.
As far as I understood, DFT of a circulant matrix should also be a circulant matrix. But when I define a circulant matrix in Matlab and check the elements of its DFT, It does not appear to be a circulant matrix. If my assumption for circular symmetry is wrong in the first place, could you explain why it is the case?

````
circ_mat = zeros(13,13); % define an empty matrix to fill in

% define a vector
rand_vec = [0.3268    0.8803    0.4711    0.4040    0.1792    0.9689    0.4075    0.8445    0.6153    0.3766    0.8772    0.7849    0.4650]

% prodecure to create a circulant matrix
for i = 1:13
    circ_mat(i,:) = rand_vec;
    last = rand_vec(end);
    rand_vec = [rand_vec(end) rand_vec];
    rand_vec(end) = [];
end

CIRC_MAT = fft2(circ_mat); % fft of the circulant matrix

```
````

Comment: Why did you expect the DFT to be circulant? Also, circulant matrix is not circularly symmetric. Circularly symmetric would mean that you can rotate it over any angle and get the same matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The DFT diagonalizes a [*Circulant Matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

So, if $ \boldsymbol{C} \in \mathcal{C} $ where $ \mathcal{C} $ is the set of circulant matrices, then:

$$ \boldsymbol{D} = {F}^{H} \boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{F} $$

Where $ \boldsymbol{F} $ is the unitary form of the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix and $ \boldsymbol{D} $ is a diagonal matrix where its diagonal is composed of the DFT of the sequence which defines $ \boldsymbol{C} $:

$$ \boldsymbol{D} = \operatorname{Diag} \left( \boldsymbol{F} \boldsymbol{c} \right) $$

Where $ \boldsymbol{c} = {\left[ {c}_{0}, {c}_{1}, \ldots, {c}_{n - 1}  \right]}^{T} $.

One simple way to generate a circulant matrix is:

```matlab
function [ mC ] = GenerateCirculantMatrix( vC )

mX = ifft( fft( diag( fft(vC) ), [], 1 ), [], 2, 'symmetric' );

end
```

Basically, it generates a matrix just like the definition above.
If `vC` is a symmetric real vector, the generated matrix will be real and symmetric.